# Confusing end of line characters in Vim

Tags: linux, vim

How to view in Vim if there is any end of line character at the end of the file?

If file content is '1234' as by `echo -n 1234 > file.txt` Vim shows (with `:set list` option) '1234$'.

If file content is '1234\n' as by `echo 1234 > file.txt` Vim again shows '1234$'.

How do I distinguish between these two different contents if they are shown as same?

Is there any other way how to inspect EOL chars using Linux default tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `list` option doesn't show that there is an EOL character at the end line, it shows where the end of the line is.

When the buffer is loaded you should see something like this in the first case (no EOL):

```
"file.txt" [noeol] 1L, 4C
```

and something like this in the second case (EOL):

```
"file.txt" 1L, 5C
```

Note the `[noeol]` in the first case and the different character count.

Comment: I see. And writing to file in Vim will automatically place EOL to the end? Can this be disabled?

Comment: Yes but that would not be a very good idea.

Comment: I know. It was just out of curiosity.